# How to remove everything before a specific tag innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which generates a bunch of span tags one after another, some are slightly unique with a unique class given to it...I would like to find a function that deletes/clears everything before a certain tag....so this is what the html would look like:

```
    <div id="wordsBox">
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span class="lastword">bla</span>
        <br />
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
    </div>
```

Basically when it hits the class lastWord when I am cycling through the spans,  want to delete the it and the spans before it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

```js
$(".lastword")  //select the div with the class
    .prevAll()  //select all of the previous siblings
    .addBack()  //adds the "lastword" element into the collection
    .remove();  //remove the elements
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordsBox">
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span class="lastword">bla</span>
        <br />
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sweet as thanks! Also just saw this running code snippet thing! Very cool!

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
$( "#wordsBox .lastword" ).prevAll().remove();
$( "#wordsBox .lastword" ).remove();
```

Comment: <want to delete the it and the spans before it.>  your code just remove the spans before .lastword without removing it